# Geb test withWindow not found

Tags: java, selenium, geb, jbehave

In our application is a simple input field that will open a new window when the enter key is pressed. With a plain geb test I could have write this:

```
withNewWindow({ inputField << Keys.ENTER }, wait:true){ at(TargetPage) }
```

but now we introduced jbehave and as a result we got the test steps (in my opinion it would be the same if we would use spock or any other framework).

Now our test will become:

```
class StartPageSteps extends GebTest {

    @When("enter is pressed")
    void pressEnter() {
        at StartPage
        inputField << Keys.ENTER
    }

    @Then("target page was opened")
    void targetPageWasOpened() {
        withWindow({$('title').text() == 'title'}){at(TargetPage)}
    }
}
```

And still seperate classes to describe the pages (reduced version):

```
class StartPage extends Page {
    static  at =  { title == "StartPage" }
    static url = "..."
    static content = {
        inputField { $("input")}
    }
}

class TargetPage extends Page {
    static at = { title == "title"}
}
```

But this fails with a `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Could not find a window that would match the specification`
I can see how the new window gets open and the title is right. I also tried other attributes to locate the window and used wait statements.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`Page.getTitle()`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/Page.html#getTitle%28%29) to retrieve current page title, `$('title')` won't work. Your code should be:

```
@Then("target page was opened")
void targetPageWasOpened() {
    withWindow({title == 'title'}) {at(TargetPage)}
}
```

**EDIT**

If the window is opened asynchronously then you can wrap your code with a `waitFor()` call.

```
@Then("target page was opened")
void targetPageWasOpened() {
    waitFor {
        withWindow({ isAt TargetPage }) { true }
    }
}
```

`isAt()` will suppress any assertion errors and will return false if you're not on `TargetPage`. If a window with that page is not found then `withWindow()` will throw `NoSuchWindowException` imposing another loop inside of `waitFor()` closure. If the window is found then true will be returned and the `waitFor()` will complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my tests extend `GebTest` class and are just using the Pages (which extend `Page`). So in my context your solution will cause `No signature of method: static geb.Page.getTitle()`. I will add this to my question.

Comment: ok, the hint was right. `getPage().getTitle()` is the solution.

Comment: If you are extending from `GebTest` then Geb's `methodMissing()` magic will kick in and simply `title` will be an equivalent of `getPage().getTitle()`

Comment: You're right. Didn't test your correct answer before, sorry. Thought it was in the Page context.

Comment: Somehow it's related to the root problem: How to wait in the window specification block? Local tests work fine but testing against an application on a remote server fails but I can see that the new window appears also. I'm 99% sure it's related to timing problems.

Comment: I think that the easiest way here would be to wrap the whole `withWindow()` call with a `wait()` call

Comment: I tried that in many (wrong) ways. Do you have any hint how to wrap and what to wrap in a wait statement / closure?